# Remove database reference from workspace

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm struggling to find an answer to this one one way or the other, but can I affect the workspace from Lotusscript?  I am developing a lotus notes application that opens other lotus notes databases, however at the moment each time one of them is opened it leaves behind a dangling reference on the workspace.  Is there a way I can prevent the regency being created, delete it once it's created, or have them all cleared off a user's workspace via a domino policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NotesUIWorkspace.OpenDatabase()` method has an optional argument (see doc [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENDATABASE_METHOD.html) and note the 'temp' parameter) that you can use to prevent adding databases to the workspace.